# Converting between sea level and surface pressure values in HRRR dataset

Tags: barometric-pressure

https://rapidrefresh.noaa.gov/hrrr/

In this dataset's GRIB format files, there are two variables representing an atomspheric pressure forecast: (output as opened with pygrib)

41:MSLP (MAPS System Reduction):Pa (instant):lambert:meanSea:level 0:fcst time 0 hrs:from 202111241700

62:Surface pressure:Pa (instant):lambert:surface:level 0:fcst time 0 hrs:from 202111241700

I'm trying to understand how can I convert the pressure values between the two using [barometric formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula) so that I only need to store 1 copy of the pressure grid, preferably only the MSLP pressure because they are aligned to MSL=0.

According to the [MAPS algorithm](https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/mwre/118/10/1520-0493_1990_118_2099_aaslpr_2_0_co_2.xml?tab_body=pdf) used for HRRR's sea level correction (page 2100), the sea level pressure is calculated from computing the temperature at sea level using the 700 hPa level temperature, but I tried regenerating the surface pressure values from sea level pressure and they don't match up so well (averaging > 2 hPa difference).

I'm wondering could someone help shed light on how the MSLP grid and the SP grid in HRRR are created and whether there exists a conversion formula between the two?

First question on this site. Thanks a lot in advance for your help!